# i used autopytoexe and the exe folder is very large

Tags: python, kivymd

i used autopytoexe that comes with python to make a executable python script and in my script i used kivymd and the exe file size is about 300mb is it normale to be that big even my script is not large  and on top of that the exe file is not working

this is my app code

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatIconButton, MDFillRoundFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from random import randrange
import time
from kivy.core.window import Window


#verbs and answers
verbs = ["arise", "awake", "be", "bear", "beat", "become", "begin", "bend", "bet", "bind", "bite", "bleed", "blow", "break", "breed", "bring", "broadcast", "build", "burn", "burst"]
answers =["arose", "awoke", "was", "bore", "beat", "became", "began", "bent", "bet", "bound", "bit", "bled", "blew", "broke", "bred", "brought", "broadcast", "built", "burnt", "burst"]
answer2 =["arisen", "awoken", "been", "born", "beat", "become", "begun", "bent", "bet", "bound", "bitten", "bled", "blown", "broken", "bred", "brought", "broadcast", "built", "burnt", "burst"]











class englishlearnApp(MDApp):
    def outofrange(self):
        self.verbs = self.verbscopy
        self.answers = self.answerscopy
        self.answer2 = self.answer2copy
        self.range = 20
        self.label.text = 'you passed all 20 verbs congrats !'
        self.verbsleft = ''

        




    def flip(self):
        self.verbs = self.verbscopy
        self.answers = self.answerscopy
        self.answer2 = self.answer2copy
        self.range = 20
        self.target = randrange(0, self.range)

        self.verbsleft.text = str(self.range)  + ' verbs left'
        self.verbans.text = self.verbs[self.target]



    def check_answer(self, instance):
        if self.input1.text == self.answers[self.target] and self.input2.text == self.answer2[self.target]:
            
                print('it happened')
                self.label.text = 'yes! '
                self.answers.remove(self.answers[self.target])
                self.answer2.remove(self.answer2[self.target])
                self.verbs.remove(self.verbs[self.target])
                self.range = self.range - 1
                self.verbsleft.text = str(self.range) + ' verbs left'
                if int(self.range) > 0:
                    self.target = randrange(0, self.range)
                elif int(self.range) == 0:
                    self.outofrange()
                
                self.verbans.text = ' what is the simple past of : \n' + self.verbs[self.target]
                self.input1.text = ''
                self.input2.text = ""
            
            
            


        elif self.input1.text == self.answers[self.target] and self.input2.text != self.answer2[self.target]:
            self.label.text = 'no ' + self.input2.text + ' is not the answer  , the past participale of the verb ' + self.verbs[self.target] + ' is : ' + self.answer2[self.target]
            self.target = randrange(0, self.range)
            self.verbans.text =  self.verbs[self.target]
            self.input1.text = ''
            self.input2.text = ""
            self.verbsleft.text = str(self.range) + ' verbs left'





        elif self.input1.text != self.answers[self.target] and self.input2.text == self.answer2[self.target]:
            self.label.text = 'no ' + self.input1.text + ' is not the answer , the simple past of the verb ' + self.verbs[self.target] +  ' is : ' + self.answers[self.target]
            self.target = randrange(0, self.range)
            self.verbans.text =  self.verbs[self.target]            
            self.input1.text = ''
            self.input2.text = ""
            self.verbsleft.text = str(self.range) + ' verbs left'




        else:
            self.label.text = 'wrong , the past participale is  ' + self.answers[self.target] + ' and the simple past is  ' + self.answer2[self.target] 
            self.target = randrange(0, self.range)
            self.verbans.text =  self.verbs[self.target]            
            self.input1.text = ''
            self.input2.text = ""
            self.verbsleft.text = str(self.range) + ' verbs left'





    def build(self):
        Window.size = (900, 1000)
        self.verbs = ["arise", "awake", "be", "bear", "beat", "become", "begin", "bend", "bet", "bind", "bite", "bleed", "blow", "break", "breed", "bring", "broadcast", "build", "burn", "burst"]
        self.answers =["arose", "awoke", "was", "bore", "beat", "became", "began", "bent", "bet", "bound", "bit", "bled", "blew", "broke", "bred", "brought", "broadcast", "built", "burnt", "burst"]
        self.answer2 =["arisen", "awoken", "been", "born", "beat", "become", "begun", "bent", "bet", "bound", "bitten", "bled", "blown", "broken", "bred", "brought", "broadcast", "built", "burnt", "burst"]


        self.verbscopy = self.verbs.copy()
        self.answerscopy = self.answers.copy()
        self.answer2copy = self.answer2.copy()









        self.range = 20
        self.target = randrange(0, self.range)
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepOrange"
        screen = MDScreen()
        #UI Widgets go here
        #top toolbar
        self.toolbar = MDToolbar(title= 'english learning(20 verbs version) ')
        self.toolbar.pos_hint = {"top":1}
        self.toolbar.right_action_items = [["rotate-3d-variant", lambda x : self.flip()]]
        screen.add_widget(self.toolbar)

        #logo
        #screen.add_widget(Image(source='cat.png', pos_hint = {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.2}))

        #get an input
        self.input1 = MDTextField(text = "", halign='center', size_hint = (0.8,1), pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.65}, font_size = 22)
        self.input2 = MDTextField(text = "", halign='center', size_hint = (0.8,1), pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.55}, font_size = 22)



        #labels
        self.verbsleft = MDLabel(text = str(self.range) + ' verbs left', halign='center', pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.15, 'center_y':0.8}, theme_text_color = 'Primary')

        self.label = MDLabel(text = '', halign='center', pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.83}, theme_text_color = 'Secondary')
        self.verbans = MDLabel(text = self.verbs[self.target],halign='center', pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.75}, theme_text_color = 'Primary', font_style = 'H5')

        self.bymetxt = MDLabel(text = 'by @YA_KI_NE', halign='center', pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y':0.1}, theme_text_color = 'Hint')


        self.whatis1 = MDLabel(text = 'the simple past : ', halign='center', pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.2, 'center_y':0.65}, theme_text_color = 'Secondary')
        self.whatis2 = MDLabel(text = 'the participale past :', halign='center', pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.2, 'center_y':0.55}, theme_text_color = 'Secondary')

        screen.add_widget(self.verbsleft)
        screen.add_widget(self.whatis1)
        screen.add_widget(self.whatis2)
        screen.add_widget(self.label)
        screen.add_widget(self.verbans)
        screen.add_widget(self.bymetxt)
        

        


        #button
        screen.add_widget(MDFillRoundFlatButton(text="check answer",font_size = 17 , pos_hint = {"center_x" : 0.5,"center_y":0.38}, on_press = self.check_answer))



        screen.add_widget(self.input1)
        screen.add_widget(self.input2)
        return screen




if __name__ == '__main__':
    englishlearnApp().run()
```

if u wanna help me and create an apk file ill apreaciate it :)

Comment: did you create venv?

Comment: no i just followed a youtube tutorial

Comment: so, its not about your code. when you create an exe from python script it includes every package. You have to create virtual env., install packages used in script and create a exe as you did. you could find examples/tutorials online. and exe file probably will be 10-20mb.

Comment: oh thank u very much i apreaciate that